# How to see if there are any qbittorent torrents from shell script?

Tags: scripts, bittorrent, qbittorrent, torrent-client

I run a script on startup that opens a browser, irc, and qbittorrent. It looks similar to this:

```
chromium-browser &
qbittorrent &
xchat &
guake &
```

Is there any way I can detect if there are any "active" torrents and only open qbittorrent if yes? By active I mean any torrent in the client, not necessarily downloading (they're not downloading anyway if it's closed).

Comment: just out of curiosity what is so important about `qbittorrent` if you need to download or seed a torrent you can do it manually whenever you like :-)

Comment: @JohnnyD. I can open xchat, chromium and guake manually also whenever I like. This is to help me so I don't have to remember that I have pending torrents and open it manually, so it will download in the background.

Answer (score 1):

What about checking the directory you've configured `qbittorent` to store .torrent files in?

Under Options > Downloads, take a look at the Copy `Keep incomplete torrents in` setting and select a location.

[image]

Simply modifying your start up script to check this directory for .torrent files that haven't completed yet might be good enough.

If not, and you need a little more functionality, then, enable the `Run an external program on torrent completion` setting and write a simple script that does whatever additional things you want.

Anyways, the point is, a combination of these various settings and scripts can be used to do a number of things with `qbittorrent` depending on what you want.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the option of directory in qbittorrent. What's the default?

Comment: I will fire up a Ubuntu box and get it loaded up so I can add some more details here. Stay tuned!

Comment: Updated the answer as promised. :)

Comment: The first option is to keep the actual files, *not* the .torrent file afaict. The second option won't really help because I can't tell from the script if I finished downloading the *last* torrent or there are still more. If there was a "run a script when *all* torrents are finished", then...